# Unique values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

Hi so I've just started learning python.And I am trying to learn pandas and I have this doubt on how to find the unique start and stop values in a data frame.Can someone help me out here

Comment: Can you provide an example of your dataframe and the expected output? You can also read [how to write good questions for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), this makes it much easier to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide an example dataset, let's assume this one:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': np.random.randint(0,10,5),
                   'stop':  np.random.randint(0,10,5),
                  }).T.apply(sorted).T
```

```
   start  stop
0      0     5
1      1     8
2      7     9
3      5     6
4      0     9
```

To get unique values for a given column (here `start`):

```
>>> df['start'].unique()
array([0, 1, 7, 5])
```

For all columns at once:

```
>>> df.apply(pd.unique, result_type='reduce')
start    [0, 1, 7, 5]
stop     [5, 8, 9, 6]
dtype: object
```